# Does anyone recognize this bug?

Tags: pest-control, pest

We have had this type of bug in our house every year during the summer only. They like to stay in the dining room and kitchen only. They stay only on the ceiling and walls until they are disturbed. They fly minimally. We don't leave fruit or vegetables outside the fridge. The only produce outside the fridge are onions and potatoes. They multiply very quickly.

[image]

Comment: Can you give a measurement of the size?

Comment: Very small. About 3 mm

Comment: That looks like a common Fly.

Comment: You might take a sharper picture and search by image, or just see if you recognize it: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=types+of+flies . Might be a black fly, found near water. Or not.

Comment: Google image search agrees it's a fly. Fruit flies are notorious for spawning in huge quantities if they can find moisture and something to feed on...

Comment: Yes, a fruit fly

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of the myriad types of drosophila - known alternatively as fruit flies, tea-bag flies or houseplant flies… for where they breed.

They don't need 'fruit' per se. They like damp & nutritious - your waste bin, or the peat/compost in your houseplants.
If they're in the bin you need to empty it more frequently, or separate out anything with moisture & get that outdoors immediately.
If they're in your plant soil, you need to water them less. Let the top dry out before carefully re-watering [this is a fine balance between killing the flies & killing the plants.]
You can spray them with common fly killer - but watch for pets & children. Spraying the air, bin or plants doesn't really work for more than a day, as they breed rapidly.

Comment: I concur, I see them often buzzing around the compost bins.  Sometimes I see odd ones that are probably  a cross between the house fly and fruit fly.